# Change font- color when overlapping footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed  menu that is attached to the left side of the screen. I need the links to be white, but once they overlap the footer the letters that are on top of he footer need to change to #333 ecause the footer background is white and hence the links not visible any longer. How can this be achieved? I have the folloing html:

```
<div class="container">
<nav>
<ul id="fixed">
<li><a href="Menu item</li>
<li><a href="Menu item</li>
<li><a href="Menu item</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<footer id="mainfooter"></footer>
```

and my css is

```
.fixed{
position:absolute;
left: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
}
```

I tried mixx-blend-mode but this does not achieve what I need.

Comment: Where is the connection to javascript?

Comment: @Reporter I tink this can only be achived with js.